# Heteroskedasticity, autocorrelation robust standard errors for SPSS

Tags: regression, spss, standard-error, heteroscedasticity

Is there a way of performing HAC robust standard errors in SPSS?

Comment: You mean a way of *calculating* HAC robust standard error *estimates*, right? Do you have a particular method you want to use?

Comment: @guest - Yes! I'm using GEE Negative Binomial regression, controlling for temporal correlation on longitudinal count data.

Comment: Use `sandwich` in R. Or `robust` option in Stata. A year and a half of waiting time is definitely worth the price of Stata :).

Answer (score 2):

Since this question has not been answered for over a year and I stumbled upon an article with a macro for the simple HC correlation I thought it might be worth mentioning. The article is available [here](http://www.afhayes.com/public/BRM2007.pdf) and has at the end a macro that allows for HC calculation. Using the R code from the [sandwich-package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/index.html) `vcovHAC` (esp. the `meatHAC`) functions it might be feasible to create a macro for SPSS that handles HAC errors.

That said, why not just go with R and the `sandwich`-package? You can even work inside SPSS with R using the [essentials for R](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ibmspssstat/)-addon.